# Use of " _ " in functions Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

If I have a function that hasn't arguments and works on a list, like :

```
let listToCheck = function
 [] -> raise (Failure "No elements")
 | hd :: tl -> returnTrueOrFalse _ (*Where "_" should be the list*)
```

With `returnTrueOrFalse` defined as :

```
let returnTrueOrFalse list_ = .... (*returns true or false*)
.
(*some code*)
.
let isTrue = listToCheck [1;2;3] in isTrue
```

Now, `listToCheck` is called on a list and hasn't paramenters.

On the other hand `returnTrueOrFalse` needs of an argument.

Since `listToCheck` is a function to call on a list, can I pass that list as argument for `returnTrueOrFalse` using `_` inside `listToCheck` ? If yes, how?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*using anonymous functions*" or why you would want to do this. Can't you just write `print_string (if returnTrueOrFalse [1;2;4;8] then "True" else "False");;`?

Comment: I changed a little the question, it isn't on the functions but more on " _ ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconstruct the list, or alias the pattern, or just don't split into head and tail at all:

```
let listToCheck = function
  | []       -> raise (Failure "No elements")
  | hd :: tl -> returnTrueOrFalse (hd::tl)
```

```
let listToCheck = function
  | []                 -> raise (Failure "No elements")
  | (hd :: tl) as list -> returnTrueOrFalse list
```

```
let listToCheck = function
  | []   -> raise (Failure "No elements")
  | list -> returnTrueOrFalse list
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly this is what I was looking for, "as list"! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't really need to do a pattern match at all:

```
let listToCheck list =
    if list = [] then failwith "No elements"
    else returnTrueOrFalse list
```

However you're probably asking a more general question, not about this particular code. For the general case I think the `as` pattern is probably what you're looking for, as @Bergi suggests.